# Find the range of $a$ for $a^2 - bc - 8a + 7 = 0$ and $b^2 + c^2 + bc - 6 a + b = 0$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers such that

\begin{cases}
a^2 - bc - 8a + 7 = 0\\
b^2 + c^2 + bc - 6 a + b = 0\\
\end{cases}

Find the range of $a$.

By adding the two equations I have $$(a - 7)^2 + (b + \frac 12)^2 + c^2 = \frac {169}4,$$
thus $a \in [\frac 12, \frac {27}2]$. Then I found that $a$ cannot obtain the boundaries so $a \in (\frac 12, \frac {27}2)$. But this is only a rough restriction. Exactly how do I solve this?

Edit: When I got this question from my friend, it was a $b$, but after I saw the official solution, it should be a $6$ instead. So the official answer I posted is actually not the answer to the question here but the answer to the original question. I'm really sorry for this mistake.

Comment: @Chip I tried but that doesn't yield any solution? There are still many variables and the equation is not even homogeneous! How do I deal with that?

Comment: From the first equation, you can write $a=F_1(b,c)$ (two functions, as it is a quadratic equation). From the second equation you can: (1) write $a=F_2(b,c)$ and (2) replace $a$ by $F_1(b,c)$ which gives you a condition $F_3(b,c)=$. Now, you can approach this using the Lagrange multiplier: "maximize/minimize $F_2(b,c)$  given the constraint $F_3(b,c)=0$.

Comment: You also can think about as two curves that depend on the parameter $a$: the first one is a hyperbola and the second one is an ellipse. You already know the maximum range of $a$. You can see this in Geogebra. For some values there is no solution still, while for others the hyperbola is tangent to the ellipse (probably those $a$ values are the ones that define the intervals you search).

Comment: @Chip Sorry, I'm still not sure how to do this. Could you please work it out and post it as an answer?

Comment: is rather tedious to do by hand. I can make another suggestion that will solve it: your second equations defines an ellipse in plane (b,c). Just rotate (b,c) by $\pi/4$ radians and you get the ellipse. You can parametrize an ellipse with semi-axes given by the polar angle $\phi$. The semi-axes now depend on your parameter $a$. If you replace the parametrized (b,c) in the first equation you get something like $\sin(2\phi)=f(a)$. Hence, now you reduced the problem to finding those values of $a$ for which a solution exists, ie $\vert f(a) \vert \le 1$.

Comment: An even simpler solution: consider $(b,c)$ as $(x,y)$ coordinates and $a$ a parameter. Then $(b,c)$ are on a circle with radius $R=R(a)$ (you wrote it yourself). All you need to do is to see when the hyperbola defined by first equation intersects the circle or not. Maybe the limits of the interval for $a$ are given when the two curves are tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen the official answer, I conclude that the question was entered wrongly; the last $b$ in the second equation should have been a $6$. Nevertheless, I leave here my finding of the range with the originally entered $b$.

Use $x$ for $b$, $y$ for $c$ and then rewrite the hyperbola and circle equations as conic sections with the free parameter $a$ on the right:
$$xy=a^2-8a+7\implies y=\frac{a^2-8a+7}x\\\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2=\frac{169}{4}-(a-7)^2$$
By plotting these two equations (e.g. in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a756i9qnvx)) we can get first insights.

- Between around $a=0.7$ and $a=9.42$ the circle (black curve in the Desmos graph) always intersects the hyperbola (blue curve); outside this range it does not. Hence the range of $a$ is around $[0.7,9.42]$.
- At the endpoints of this interval, the circle is tangent to the hyperbola, i.e. meets it in exactly one point.

Now substitute *x* for *y* in the circle equation:
$$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a^2-8a+7}x\right)^2=\frac{169}{4}-(a-7)^2$$
$$\frac{169}{4}-(a-7)^2-\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{(a^2-8a+7)^2}{x^2}$$
$$x^2\left(\frac{169}4-(a-7)^2-\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)=(a^2-8a+7)^2$$
Write $\frac{169}4-(a-7)^2$ as $K$ and $(a^2-8a+7)^2$ as $L$.
$$x^2\left(K-\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)=L$$
$$Kx^2-x^2\left(x+\frac12\right)^2=L$$
$$Kx^2-L=x^2\left(x+\frac12\right)^2=x^4+x^3+\frac{x^2}4$$
$$x^4+x^3+\left(\frac14-K\right)x^2+L=0$$
$$x^4+x^3+((a-7)^2-42)x^2+(a^2-8a+7)^2=0\tag1$$
Given a particular $a$, the real roots of (1), the red curve in Desmos, are the $x$-coordinates of all the circle/hyperbola intersections. Based on what we have established above via graphing, the endpoints of the desired range of $a$ cause (1) to have exactly one real root, which must necessarily be multiple because the equation is quartic.

The discriminant of (1) is
$$\Delta=(a^4-16 a^3+78 a^2-112 a+49) (144 a^8-3456 a^7+30668 a^6-145848 a^5+512913 a^4-1167616 a^3+1788186 a^2-1385832 a+392441)$$
and we need this to be zero. The first factor is zero if $a$ is 1 or 7, but the hyperbola degenerates into the *x*- and *y*-axes at these values and intersects the circle at four points, so 1 and 7 are not endpoints of the range of $a$. The second factor is irreducible and its real roots must be found numerically; they are
$$a_1=0.7011318910\dots\\
  a_2=0.7991926383\dots\\
  a_3=9.0808510571\dots\\
  a_4=9.4187795193\dots$$
Of these, we reject $a_2$ and $a_3$, because they give (1) three real roots. Hence the range of $a$ in the original system of equations, **the answer to the question**, is
$$a\in[a_1,a_4]=[0.7011318910\dots,9.4187795193\dots]$$

Comment: Why is this answer different from the answer I got?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie The given answer does give a valid range for a, but it's not the _maximal_ range. Just look at the Desmos graph I prepared; at $a=0.9,9.2$ the hyperbola and ellipse still intersect.

Comment: Then can you tell me what's wrong with the given answer?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie I think you made a gaffe when typesetting the _question_. If the $b$ is changed to a $6$, the official answer becomes valid.

Comment: Oh that's true! I'm really really sorry for that... Actually a friend of mine gave me this problem, and he wrote $b$ instead of $6$ (as you can see from my attempt that I didn't know that), then occasionally I found this question in a book with the official solution... Again, I'm sorry for that. I'll take your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "official" solution which I found later:
\begin{cases}
a^2 - bc - 8a + 7 = 0\\
b^2 + c^2 + bc - 6 a + \mathbf6= 0\\
\end{cases}
is equivalent to
\begin{cases}
bc=a^2 - 8a + 7\\
b+c=\pm(a-1)\\
\end{cases}
So $b,c$ are the roots of the equation
$$x^2\pm(a-1)x+(a^2-8a+7)=0$$
A necessary and sufficient condition that $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ is
$$\Delta=(a-1)^2-4(a^2-8a+7)\ge0$$ Solving this gives the answer $a\in[1,9]$.

Comment: As a clarification, I have highlighted the typo that gave so much trouble.